# Is it possible to create a search scope that is based on other scopes?

Tags: 2010, search, search-scope

[On TechNet, it clearly says "You can also create a search scope that includes several other scopes."](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185660%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it.  What I have is four scopes.  What I want is a new, fifth scope that essentially encompasses all of the other four.  I'd like to do this by using the existing four scopes, and not have to re-create all of the rules that go into each of those original scopes in the new fifth scope.

Any ideas / insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question over on the [MS TechNet SharePoint forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearchprevious/thread/90fba5cf-9c2d-4c56-97c7-302e739e163a), and according to the reply given to me there, the answer appears to be:

> No.

Dang it.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was marked as answered I would offer a method that would make scope rule management a little easier via Powershell given your needs.  Use the following powershell command inside of a powershell function (function would only create 1 scope rule) :

New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScopeRule

Then create different functions for each scope that reference the scope rule functions.

E.g.

Function CreateScopeRule1 { New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScopeRule}
Function CreateScopeRule2 { New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScopeRule }

//create scope rules for scope A

CreateScopeRule1

//create scope rules for scope B

CreateScopeRule1
CreateScopeRule2